# Can I create a Predefined Case Team in an APEX test class?

Tags: unit-test

In a Test Class, I would like to set SeeAllData=false and then create a Predefined Case Team in the setup method for use in the Test Class.  I can not find any documentation on this.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so verify it?

Comment: @RahulSharma I haven't tried anything yet. I can't find the api name to attempt to create a predefined case team using apex. So I'm asking if it is even possible to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can create a Predefined Case Team in an APEX Test Class.  It is called CaseTeamTemplate.

```
CaseTeamTemplate myCaseTeam = new CaseTeamTemplate();
myCaseTeam.name = 'TestName';
myCaseTeam.description = 'Test Description';
insert myCaseTeam;
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_caseteamtemplate.htm